# Android: add EditTextPreference as ListPreference item

Tags: android, preferences

Is there any way to add EditTextPreference as ListPreference item? What I need is RadioGroup list of preferences (ListPreference is just for that), but the last entry would be something like "Custom" where I need something like EditTextPreference to allow user to add custom value to this preference.

Any ideas how to do it?

Thanx all!

Answer (score 2):

You would have to create your own custom `DialogPreference` for this in Java. There is no way to accomplish it through the preference XML.

Comment: I tried, but I didn't succeed :(. Could you pleas look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130342/android-subclassing-dialogpreference