# Android: subclassing DialogPreference

Tags: android, preferences

I am trying to create custom dialog preference that will hold radio group with two radio buttons and one edittext. If I write something like 
 
`<DialogPreference android:title="preftitle"
            android:dialogLayout="@layout/preflayout"
            android:summary="pref summary"
            android:key="prefkey" android:defaultValue="defaultValue" />`
 
the application breaks when trying to create PreferenceActivity that holds this dialog preference. 
 
I guess I have to subclass DialogPreference and put that subclass as xml element. But I don't know what methods should I override and how.

Could anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concise way of writing new DialogPreference classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505845/concise-way-of-writing-new-dialogpreference-classes)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look here,

[creating a DialogPreference from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365310/creating-a-dialogpreference-from-xml)

You are correct, you need to subclass DialogPreference.