# creating a DialogPreference from XML

Tags: android, xml, preference

I have been attempting to use an `android.preference.DialogPreference` inflated from XML, but the documentation seems to be missing some essential bits, and I cannot find a working example anywhere.  My XML now looks like this (I tried many permutations but this seems like a reasonable minimum):

```
<DialogPreference
android:key="funThing" android:title="Fun Thing"
android:dialogLayout="@layout/fun_layout"
android:positiveButtonText="OK"
android:negativeButtonText="Cancel"
/>
```

My supposition at this point is that it is required to subclass `DialogPreference` and not to use it directly. For one, I cannot find a way to associate the actual preference value with an element in the dialog itself, which upon reflection is kind of a giveaway.  And also, looking at [the source to `DialogPreference.java`](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/preference/DialogPreference.java) seems to confirm it. And I also just noticed that [the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html) refers to it as a "base class". But at very least, it would be nice to establish a definitive-enough source on the net which would help the next N people figure this out faster than I did.

For the record, the logfile looks like this:

```
I/ActivityManager(   61): Starting: Intent { cmp=org.jeremy.android/.PreferencesActivity } from pid 2755
W/Resources( 2755): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x4b0 a=-1}
W/Resources( 2755): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x20 a=-1}
D/AndroidRuntime( 2755): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 2755): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.jeremy.android/org.jeremy.android.PreferencesActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:397)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:417)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:428)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:481)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:251)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:262)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at org.jeremy.android.PreferencesActivity.onCreate(PreferencesActivity.java:40)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: android.preference.DialogPreference
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:383)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2755):    ... 22 more
W/ActivityManager(   61):   Force finishing activity org.jeremy.android/.PreferencesActivity
W/ActivityManager(   61):   Force finishing activity org.jeremy.android/.SplashActivity
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This one is weird, you need to subclass `DialogPreference`. The subclass does not need to do anything. So

```
public class MyDialogPreference extends DialogPreference {

    public MyDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

can be instantiated. While a plane old `DialogPreference` can not. Very weird, they should be the exact same thing.

Comment: Not that weird if you notice that DialogPreference is an abstract class.

Answer (score 41):

Here is an example of how to use the dialog preference (subclassing as you mentioned).

```java
package dk.myapp.views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

/**
 * The OptionDialogPreference will display a dialog, and will persist the
 * <code>true</code> when pressing the positive button and <code>false</code>
 * otherwise. It will persist to the android:key specified in xml-preference.
 */
public class OptionDialogPreference extends DialogPreference {

    public OptionDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);
        persistBoolean(positiveResult);
    }

}
```

The preferences.xml should contain

```xml
<dk.myapp.views.OptionDialogPreference
            android:key="@string/prefKeyResetQuests"
            android:dialogIcon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert"
            android:title="Reset Quests"
            android:summary="Reset all quest-progress."
            android:dialogMessage="Are you sure you wish to reset your quest progress? This action cannot be undone!"
            android:positiveButtonText="Clear Quests"
            android:negativeButtonText="Cancel"/>
```

I have a res/value containing (though the key-name can also be declared explicitly above).

```xml
<string name="prefKeyResetQuests">resetQuests</string>
```

My PreferenceActivity does the actual resetting from onPause. Note that onStop may be too late since the onStop will not always be called immediately after pressing back:

```java
@Override
public void onPause() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = android.preference.PreferenceManager.
        getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    if(prefs.getBoolean(
        getResources().getString(R.string.prefKeyResetQuests), false)) {
        // apply reset, and then set the pref-value back to false
    }
}
```

Or equivalently since we are still in the PreferenceActivity:

```java
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Preference prefResetQuests =
        findPreference(getResources().getString(R.string.prefKeyResetQuests));
    if(prefResetQuests.getSharedPreferences().
        getBoolean(prefResetQuests.getKey(), false)){
        // apply reset, and then set the pref-value back to false 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great info. Only I did not like using 'this.findPreferences' but used 'this.getContext( ).getSharedPreferences'

Comment: How can i show this DialogPreference via java code?

Answer (score 15):

#### First:

Create your own class which extends `DialogPreference` as bellow:

```
package com.test.view;

import android.preference.DialogPreference;

public class DialogExPreference extends DialogPreference 
{
    public DialogExPreference(Context oContext, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(oContext, attrs);     
    }
}
```

#### Second:

Modify the xml file as bellow:

```
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <com.test.view.DialogExPreference
        android:title="@string/title"
        android:dialogMessage="@string/lite"              
                android:negativeButtonText="test"/> 

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Then it's OK.

Comment: how can i show this dialog preference programmatically?