# Cannot resolve method 'SetPositiveButton'

Tags: android, methods, resolve

I'm doing some really basics programming at Android Studio.
I getting this error on the screen:

> Cannot resolve method 'SetPositiveButton'

Is there any `import` that I'm missing?

Here is my complete code:

```
package com.kontrol.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class SS1_Senha extends DialogPreference implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener{

    public SS1_Senha(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setPersistent(false);
        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.ss1_senha);

        SetPositiveButtonText("OK");
        SetPositiveButtonText("Cancelar")


        setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                //Action after OK

            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: can you check my answer below

Comment: Also, you might want to check out the docs of `DialogPreference` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html) - was that so hard to find? Also, java method names are `lowerCamelCase` not `UpperCamelCase`. `setPositiveButtonText` actually exists!

Comment: Cmon, guys! You must be kidding... Do you really think that I didnt read all of these before asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8818446/1668144) answer and do your DialogPreference directly in the XML:

```
<com.kontrol.app.SS1_Senha
            android:key="@string/the_key"
            android:dialogIcon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert"
            android:title="@string/your_title"
            android:summary="@string/your_summary"
            android:dialogMessage="@string/your_text"
            android:positiveButtonText="Ok"
            android:negativeButtonText="Cancelar"/>
```

Comment: The issue is that I cannot even get the listener like:

`setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                //Action after OK
}
}
)`

Answer (score 3):

try this please:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);  
        // set title 
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("some text");
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("some text")
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton( "Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            try {
               //so some work
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                 //Exception
            }
            }
          })
        .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            //do something if you need
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
                alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are seeing this method

setPositiveButton(CharSequence text, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)

When you start typing .setPos..., select the above option.