# Android: Implement Multi Spinner Search in preferences dialog

Tags: android, android-listview, android-preferences, android-multiselectlistpreference

I need to let the user to choose city in the preferences, there are many cities so I used [this](https://github.com/pratikbutani/MultiSelectSpinner) project to search in the list, its working great, but I need to implement it inside preferences xml, and not in a regular layout.

here is what I had before, [Main Activity class, works fine in regular layout]:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /**
         * Getting array of String to Bind in Spinner
         */
        final List<String> list = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sports_array));

/**
 * Search MultiSelection Spinner (With Search/Filter Functionality)
 * 
 *  Using MultiSpinnerSearch class
 */
MultiSpinnerSearch searchSpinner = (MultiSpinnerSearch) findViewById(R.id.searchMultiSpinner);
final List<KeyPairBoolData> listArray = new ArrayList<KeyPairBoolData>();

for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    KeyPairBoolData h = new KeyPairBoolData();
    h.setId(i+1);
    h.setName(list.get(i));
    h.setSelected(false);
    listArray.add(h);
}

/***
 * -1 is no by default selection
 * 0 to length will select corresponding values 
 */
searchSpinner.setItems(listArray, "Multi Selection With Filter", -1, new MultiSpinnerSearchListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemsSelected(List<KeyPairBoolData> items) {

        for(int i=0; i<items.size(); i++) {
            if(items.get(i).isSelected()) {
                Log.i("TAG", i + " : " + items.get(i).getName() + " : " + items.get(i).isSelected());
            }
        }
    }
});
}
```

in the layout I had:

```
<com.androidbuts.multispinnerfilter.MultiSpinnerSearch
        android:id="@+id/searchMultiSpinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >
    </com.androidbuts.multispinnerfilter.MultiSpinnerSearch>
```

and the original class was:

```
public class MultiSpinnerSearch extends Spinner implements OnCancelListener {

    private List<KeyPairBoolData> items;
    //private boolean[] selected;
    private String defaultText;
    private MultiSpinnerSearchListener listener;
    MyAdapter adapter;

    public MultiSpinnerSearch(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MultiSpinnerSearch(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public MultiSpinnerSearch(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // refresh text on spinner

        StringBuffer spinnerBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            if (items.get(i).isSelected() == true) {
                spinnerBuffer.append(items.get(i).getName());
                spinnerBuffer.append(", ");
            }
        }

        String spinnerText = "";
        spinnerText = spinnerBuffer.toString();
        if (spinnerText.length() > 2)
            spinnerText = spinnerText.substring(0, spinnerText.length() - 2);
        else
            spinnerText = defaultText;

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSpinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                R.layout.textview_for_spinner,
                new String[] { spinnerText });
        setAdapter(adapterSpinner);

        if(adapter != null)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        listener.onItemsSelected(items);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setTitle(defaultText);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_listview_search, null);
        builder.setView(view);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.alertSearchListView);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        listView.setFastScrollEnabled(false);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.alertSearchEditText);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {  
            }
        });

        //builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items.toArray(new CharSequence[items.size()]), selected, this);
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

//              items = (ArrayList<KeyPairBoolData>) adapter.arrayList;

                Log.i("TAG", " ITEMS : " + items.size() );
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.setOnCancelListener(this);
        builder.show();
        return true;
    }

    public void setItems(List<KeyPairBoolData> items, String allText, int position,
            MultiSpinnerSearchListener listener) {

        this.items = items;
        this.defaultText = allText;
        this.listener = listener;

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSpinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                R.layout.textview_for_spinner,
                new String[] { defaultText });
        setAdapter(adapterSpinner);

        if(position != -1)
        {
            items.get(position).setSelected(true);
            //listener.onItemsSelected(items);
            onCancel(null);
        }
    }

    public interface MultiSpinnerSearchListener {
        public void onItemsSelected(List<KeyPairBoolData> items);
    }

    //  // Adapter Class            
    public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

        List<KeyPairBoolData> arrayList;      
        List<KeyPairBoolData> mOriginalValues; // Original Values
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, List<KeyPairBoolData> arrayList) {
            this.arrayList = arrayList;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView textView;
            CheckBox checkBox;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;

            if (convertView == null) {

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_listview_search_subview, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alertTextView);
                holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alertCheckbox);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            final KeyPairBoolData data = arrayList.get(position);

            holder.textView.setText(data.getName());
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(data.isSelected());

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    ViewHolder temp = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                    temp.checkBox.setChecked(!temp.checkBox.isChecked());

                    int len = arrayList.size();
                    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                    {
                        if (i == position)
                        {
                            data.setSelected(!data.isSelected());
                            Log.i("TAG", "On Click Selected : " + data.getName() + " : " + data.isSelected());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            holder.checkBox.setTag(holder);

            return convertView;
        }

        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

                    arrayList = (List<KeyPairBoolData>) results.values; // has the filtered values
                    notifyDataSetChanged();  // notifies the data with new filtered values
                }

                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
                    List<KeyPairBoolData> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<KeyPairBoolData>();

                    if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                        mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<KeyPairBoolData>(arrayList); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
                    }

                    /********
                     * 
                     *  If constraint(CharSequence that is received) is null returns the mOriginalValues(Original) values
                     *  else does the Filtering and returns FilteredArrList(Filtered)  
                     *
                     ********/
                    if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                        // set the Original result to return  
                        results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                        results.values = mOriginalValues;
                    } else {
                        constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                        for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) {
                            Log.i("TAG", "Filter : " + mOriginalValues.get(i).getName() + " -> " + mOriginalValues.get(i).isSelected());
                            String data = mOriginalValues.get(i).getName();
                            if (data.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString())) {
                                FilteredArrList.add(mOriginalValues.get(i));
                            }
                        }
                        // set the Filtered result to return
                        results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                        results.values = FilteredArrList;
                    }
                    return results;
                }
            };
            return filter;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is what I'm trying to do, PreferencesSpinner Class (almost same as above):

```
public class PreferencesSpinner extends DialogPreference implements OnCancelListener {

    private List<KeyPairBoolData> items;
    public Spinner spinner;
    //private boolean[] selected;
    private String defaultText;
    private PreferencesSpinnerListener listener;
    MyAdapter adapter;

    public PreferencesSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public PreferencesSpinner(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public PreferencesSpinner(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // refresh text on spinner

        StringBuffer spinnerBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            if (items.get(i).isSelected() == true) {
                spinnerBuffer.append(items.get(i).getName());
                spinnerBuffer.append(", ");
            }
        }

        String spinnerText = "";
        spinnerText = spinnerBuffer.toString();
        if (spinnerText.length() > 2)
            spinnerText = spinnerText.substring(0, spinnerText.length() - 2);
        else
            spinnerText = defaultText;

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSpinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                R.layout.textview_for_spinner,
                new String[] { spinnerText });
        spinner.setAdapter(adapterSpinner);

        if(adapter != null)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        listener.onItemsSelected(items);
    }


    public boolean performClick() {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setTitle(defaultText);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_listview_search, null);
        builder.setView(view);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.alertSearchListView);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        listView.setFastScrollEnabled(false);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.alertSearchEditText);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

        //builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items.toArray(new CharSequence[items.size()]), selected, this);
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

//              items = (ArrayList<KeyPairBoolData>) adapter.arrayList;

                        Log.i("TAG", " ITEMS : " + items.size() );
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        builder.setOnCancelListener(this);
        builder.show();
        return true;
    }

    public void setItems(List<KeyPairBoolData> items, String allText, int position,
                         PreferencesSpinnerListener listener) {

        this.items = items;
        this.defaultText = allText;
        this.listener = listener;

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSpinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                R.layout.textview_for_spinner,
                new String[] { defaultText });
        spinner.setAdapter(adapterSpinner);

        if(position != -1)
        {
            items.get(position).setSelected(true);
            //listener.onItemsSelected(items);
            onCancel(null);
        }
    }

    public interface PreferencesSpinnerListener {
        public void onItemsSelected(List<KeyPairBoolData> items);
    }

    //  // Adapter Class
    public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

        List<KeyPairBoolData> arrayList;
        List<KeyPairBoolData> mOriginalValues; // Original Values
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, List<KeyPairBoolData> arrayList) {
            this.arrayList = arrayList;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView textView;
            CheckBox checkBox;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;

            if (convertView == null) {

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_listview_search_subview, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alertTextView);
                holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alertCheckbox);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            final KeyPairBoolData data = arrayList.get(position);

            holder.textView.setText(data.getName());
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(data.isSelected());

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    ViewHolder temp = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                    temp.checkBox.setChecked(!temp.checkBox.isChecked());

                    int len = arrayList.size();
                    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                    {
                        if (i == position)
                        {
                            data.setSelected(!data.isSelected());
                            Log.i("TAG", "On Click Selected : " + data.getName() + " : " + data.isSelected());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            holder.checkBox.setTag(holder);

            return convertView;
        }

        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

                    arrayList = (List<KeyPairBoolData>) results.values; // has the filtered values
                    notifyDataSetChanged();  // notifies the data with new filtered values
                }

                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
                    List<KeyPairBoolData> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<KeyPairBoolData>();

                    if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                        mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<KeyPairBoolData>(arrayList); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
                    }

                    /********
                     *
                     *  If constraint(CharSequence that is received) is null returns the mOriginalValues(Original) values
                     *  else does the Filtering and returns FilteredArrList(Filtered)
                     *
                     ********/
                    if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                        // set the Original result to return
                        results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                        results.values = mOriginalValues;
                    } else {
                        constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                        for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) {
                            Log.i("TAG", "Filter : " + mOriginalValues.get(i).getName() + " -> " + mOriginalValues.get(i).isSelected());
                            String data = mOriginalValues.get(i).getName();
                            if (data.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString())) {
                                FilteredArrList.add(mOriginalValues.get(i));
                            }
                        }
                        // set the Filtered result to return
                        results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                        results.values = FilteredArrList;
                    }
                    return results;
                }
            };
            return filter;
        }
    }
}
```

with Preferences.xml:

```
<com.androidbuts.multispinnerfilter.PreferencesSpinner
            android:key="spinner"
            android:title="spinner Title"
            android:summary="Summary"/>
```

and of course, Preferences class:

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {

    public PreferencesSpinner searchSpinner;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        final List<String> list = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sports_array));

        final List<KeyPairBoolData> listArray = new ArrayList<KeyPairBoolData>();

        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            KeyPairBoolData h = new KeyPairBoolData();
            h.setId(i+1);
            h.setName(list.get(i));
            h.setSelected(false);
            listArray.add(h);
        }


        searchSpinner = (PreferencesSpinner) findPreference("spinner");


        searchSpinner.setItems(listArray, "all text", -1, new PreferencesSpinner.PreferencesSpinnerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemsSelected(List<KeyPairBoolData> items) {

            }
        });
}
```

anyone can help me with the migration to preferences Activity?

Thanks!

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365310/creating-a-dialogpreference-from-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever need it, Here is the answer:

```
@Override
    protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(AlertDialog.Builder builder) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_listview_search, null);
        builder.setView(view);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.alertSearchListView);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        listView.setFastScrollEnabled(false);

        final List<String> list = Arrays.asList(view.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sports_array));

        final List<KeyPairBoolData> listArray = new ArrayList<KeyPairBoolData>();

        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            KeyPairBoolData h = new KeyPairBoolData();
            h.setId(i+1);
            h.setName(list.get(i));
            h.setSelected(false);
            listArray.add(h);
        }

        setItems(listArray, "all text", -1, new PreferencesSpinnerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemsSelected(List<KeyPairBoolData> items) {

            }
        });


        adapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.alertSearchEditText);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

        //builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items.toArray(new CharSequence[items.size()]), selected, this);
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

//              items = (ArrayList<KeyPairBoolData>) adapter.arrayList;

                        Log.i("TAG", " ITEMS : " + items.size() );
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        builder.setOnCancelListener(this);
    }
```

Hope that's help..